# windows 7 home premium vs home basic

Tags: windows-7

What is the difference between these two?

I'm trying to choose between these two for a traveling netbook (not my main system), should I really care about the Home Premium? (The price for Home Premium is more than 10% cost of the netbook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via Wikipedia: - [comparison of the windows 7 editions..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart)

- Home Basic("HB") is limited to 8GB of physical RAM on 64-bit systems ( 16GB on Home Premium ("HP"))
- HB does not have in-built DVD decoders
- HB does not have Media Center
- HB is available in [Emerging Markets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerging_markets#FTSE_list) only
- HB can only join HomeGroups, HP can create & join HomeGroups

Edit: I don't think Aero makes much sense on a netbook anyway.

Comment: Do you know What does it mean by "partial aero support"?

Comment: I think transparency is missing and the desktop effects like peak and so.

Comment: Downvote..? Seriously?

Comment: Links-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: OMG.. I guess I should have c&p'd the table then... (and how should one know that??)

Comment: 2nd downvote... Seriously guys, what's wrong with you?? Comeon! ;) It doesn't seem to be written in the FAQs so how would I know about this "rule"?

Comment: @fakem I went through this a while back you could at least describe the page in your answer....maybe edit to include "comparison of windows editions on wikipedia - page includes a simple chart"

Comment: @fake `links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.` http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231

Comment: I will include that in my next postings.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just get Home Basic, you don't need Aero or >8 GB RAM, and you can download alternatives to all of the software it doesn't include.